# How to load 1000's of data in listview efficiently

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have 1000's of customers to load in custom listview from server. But it takes more time for me to populate in listview. I am using search option to search the customers so I need to load and display all the customers at one shot. I cannot display it from the local database because I may edit the details on item click in listview and store it in server. Can any one help me loading in custom listview in an efficient way?

```
  public class CustomersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private ArrayList<Item> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;
private Item objItem;

ViewHolderSectionName holderSection;
ViewHolderName holderName;

public CustomersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);

    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    objItem = items.get(position);

    if (objItem.isSectionItem()) {
        SectionHeadersModel si = (SectionHeadersModel) objItem;

        if (convertView == null
                || !convertView.getTag().equals(holderSection)) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.alphabet_separator, null);

            holderSection = new ViewHolderSectionName();
            convertView.setTag(holderSection);
        } else {
            holderSection = (ViewHolderSectionName) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holderSection.section = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.alphabet_letter);
        holderSection.section.setText(si.getSectionString().toString());

    } else {
        CustomerListViewModel ei = (CustomerListViewModel) objItem;

        if (convertView == null || !convertView.getTag().equals(holderName)) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.customer_list_item, null);

            holderName = new ViewHolderName();
            convertView.setTag(holderName);
        } else {
            holderName = (ViewHolderName) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holderName.name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CustomerName);
        holderName.email = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CustomerEmail);
        holderName.phone = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.CustomerPhone);

        if (holderName.name != null)
            holderName.name.setText(ei.getCustomerName());
        holderName.email.setText(ei.getCustomerEmail());
        holderName.phone.setText(ei.getCustomerPhone());
    }
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolderName {
    public TextView name;
    public TextView email;
    public TextView phone;
}

public static class ViewHolderSectionName {
    public TextView section;
}
```

}

Comment: are you using `ViewHolder`? try posting code.

Comment: Use pagination with ViewHoler pattern ListView  and every request you can save it into DB and show from DB

Comment: use load more...functionality

Comment: you can use this to refresh and load more  https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore

Comment: All the customer details will not be available unless I press load more and i need to search customers from the list immediately when it is loaded. @GeorgeThomas

Comment: Am using ViewHolder pattern only to populate. It is getting loaded but the problem is it is taking more time to load and pagination I can't use because I need all customers in a single page. @andruboy

Comment: than you can download your all data and store into database and show all data into list using `SQLIteCursorLoader`

Comment: Just show how you did it now. Then we can propose refinements. 1000 items or a multiple in string arrays is nothing for an adapter. That should not take time. `so I need to load and display all the customers at one shot`. Nonsense. You only have to prepare all the data for the adapter. Diplayed will be maybe 10 items at once from 1000 by the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use viewHolder in your listview, it stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly. This [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BaseAdapter . see this [Link](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/) and [Link](http://strangevikas.wordpress.com/tag/how-adapter-works-in-android-android-and-adapters/)